# Flutter: Debugging issue on iOS using VS Code

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I am trying to debug my project on `iOS` on `VS Code`  but i am getting this error

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

It appears that your application still contains the default signing identifier.
Try replacing 'com.example' with your signing id in Xcode:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Error launching application on Testing’s iPhone (5).
```

It is debugging properly from `Xcode`.

here is the snap of my Xcode
[image]

and `com.example.bylst_hybrid` this is `package name` i am using for `android`, it is same for `iOS`. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: The issue is about your Bundle Identifier is still using `com.example.xxx`, which is inappropriate. You should use your own bundle identifier (e.g. `com.yourcompany.xxx`) in Flutter and rebuild the iOS project.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the wrong package name.

In Android you are using `com.example.bylst_hybrid` but in Xcode it looks like you are using `com.example.bylst-hybrid`, Where '-' is not in the package name convention.

Refer [name_convention](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#name) for more details.

Comment: i copy and paste the same but package name which i used on android, but when i start debugging, it converts the package name into ```com.example.bylst-hybrid``` this.

Comment: The answer is unrelated. Please check the error message in the question.

Comment: You should have the same package name for debug and release in Xcode. Also check PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in code

Answer (score 0):

As @Raptor mentioned in the comments, you should change the bundle id to `com.yourcompany.bylsthybrid`